# Programmatically fill in data in a UIWebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, authentication, uiwebview, nsstring

In my app, I want to be able to have the user enter their login info in a custom view and then show a UIWebView.  I want the UIWebView to be programmatically filled in with the user's username and password.  Then the UIWebView should programmatically click the login button.  I've been trying:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.L_lbsc_txtUserName.text.value='ANdrew';"];
```

but its not working.  I don't really understand how `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` works or what it's designed to do.

I think it might have something to do with what I filled in the string field above.
Here is the source code of the website I'm trying to access:

```
<div class="lgntxt">
  <div style="padding-left:3px;">
    <input name="L$lbsc$txtUserName" type="text" value=" -username-" size="10" id="L_lbsc_txtUserName" tabindex="1" class="textbox" onfocus="if(this.value == ' -username-') this.value = ''; Hide('L_lbsc_txtPasswordHelp'); Show('L_lbsc_txtPassword');" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = ' -username-';" style="width:80px;"><br>
    <img src="/podium/images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="3" height="1"><br>
    <input name="L$lbsc$txtPasswordHelp" type="text" value=" -password-" size="10" id="L_lbsc_txtPasswordHelp" tabindex="1" class="textbox" onfocus="Hide('L_lbsc_txtPasswordHelp'); Show('L_lbsc_txtPassword'); document.getElementById('L_lbsc_txtPassword').focus();" style="width:80px;display:;">
    <input name="L$lbsc$txtPassword" type="password" size="10" id="L_lbsc_txtPassword" tabindex="2" class="textbox" onkeydown="if ((event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode) == 13) {return false;};" onkeyup="if ((event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode) == 13) {__doPostBack('L$lbsc$btnLogin','');return false;};" onblur="if(this.value == '') {Show('L_lbsc_txtPasswordHelp'); Hide('L_lbsc_txtPassword');}" style="width:80px;display:none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace the username and password fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
so I've tried these and none of them work:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.myForm.myText.value='text from Obj-C';"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('L$lbsc$txtUserName').value='ANdrew';"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method takes JavaScript, executes it in the context of the document, then returns the result to you.  It appears your JavaScript is wrong.  Try:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('L$lbsc$txtUserName').value='ANdrew';"];
```

If you are unsure what a method does, go to [the iOS reference library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html), find [the class reference for the class you are using](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and scroll down to [the description of the method you are using](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a).

Comment: Thanks so much.  What method should I put this in? viewDidLoad, webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: Well it will need the page to have finished loading before you can access its contents, so `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is probably the appropriate place to put it.

Comment: I tried that and it appears not to be working.  If it is working its not showing up in the UIWebView.  Do I need to reload the view or something.

Comment: No.  Are you getting any error, or is it just being ignored?  Things I would check: does the `webView` variable hold an instance of `UIWebView` or is it nil?  Is the delegate method being called?  Have you set the delegate on the web view?  Can you run other JavaScript such as `alert("test");`?

Comment: I am using the webview delegate.  No error, just no response.  It seems to be getting ignored.  I do set the webview's delegate to self.  I put an NSLog in the webViewDidFinishLoad: and its getting called, just not responding.  I tried the alert thing and still no luck

Answer (score 3):

Bil, I was able to get mine working with the below.  Essentially, the element with Id of `'logon-field'` is just that.  I broke the JavaScript up into multiple lines so that I could insert my variable (coming from the `UITextField's` user-entered value in my custom screen, on top of my `UIWebView`) and concatenate. I put the below code in my `textFieldShouldReturn`: method in the view controller, so that this isn't run until the user is done entering in the text field.

```
NSString *logonJSStart = @"document.getElementById('logon-field').value='";

NSString *logonWithValue = [logonJSStart stringByAppendingString:self.logon.text];

NSString *logonJSFinal = [logonWithValue stringByAppendingString:@"';"]; 

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:logonJSFinal];
```